# unable a install pyspellcheck module on Linux(Raspbian)

Tags: python, linux, pip, raspbian, pyspellchecker

so I am working on Linux(Raspbian) and I am unable to install the pyspellcheck module.

so previously I managed to install it by just

```
pip install pyspellcheck
```

but recently I had to factory reset my machine and I am not able to install pyspellcheck anymore.
I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspellcheck (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyspellcheck
```

so I would just like to know how can I install it on my machine

**NOTE:I am working on a Linux machine**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a package at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/pyspellcheck/ — error 404. What are you trying to install? Do you want [pyspellchecker](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/)?

```
pip install pyspellchecker
```

Comment: Thank you so much...such a small mistake